# Possible solution for avoiding memory leak from static context reference

Tags: android, android-activity, memory-leaks, android-context

I know that memory leaks have been nearly done to death on stack overflow, but here goes another question, just to be sure...

I have a singleton class, `MyManager` which on such-and-such an event notifies listeners that something has changed. This manager manages some 'global' data structures, hence my using it.

```
public final class MyManager{

    private final static MyManager INSTANCE = new MyManager();

    private ArrayList<MyManagerListener> mListeners = new ArrayList<MyManagerListener>();


    public static void addListener(MyManagerListener l){
        if (!INSTANCE.mListeners.contains(l)) INSTANCE.mListeners.add(l);
    }

    public static void disconnect(){
        // Does calling this in Activity's onPause() avoid memory leak?
        INSTANCE.mListeners.clear();
    }

    /// Implementation of Manager stuff which includes call to mListener.doSomething();

}
```

I then of course have the interface `MyManagerListener`:

```
public interface MyManagerListener{
     public void doSomething();
}
```

And then in my Activity, I add the Activity instance to the the manager's `mListeners`, in my understanding this is creating a static reference to the Activity potentially disrupting the Activity's lifecycle, which is bad.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements MyManagerListener{

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Create potential memory leak here.
        MyManager.addListener(this);
        ...
    }

    protected void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        // does calling this fix the potential memory leak?
        MyManager.disconnect();
    }

    @Override
    public void doSomeThing(){
        //do something
    }
}
```

My question is, does my inclusion of `MyManager.disconnect()` address the potential issue? I know calling `ArrayList.clear()` sets all the objects in the list's underlying array to `null`

Answer (score 1):

You should clearly remove references in `onPause()` or `onStop()` instead of in `onResume()`.
Doing so should remove all references to your activity and therefore prevent memory leaks.

Comment: Hey. Sorry - my bad. typed question on bus...meant to have `disconnect()` in `onPause()`. Have corrected above. With this correction does this mean my approach is doing what it is supposed to in avoiding leak?

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure.

Comment: Though i would suggest not to clear complete arrayList but only the current instance if your instance list is on application context